# How to understand mechanism of Yahoo to Facebook Login?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am learning more on PHP, so I decided to understand the mechanism of Facebook in Stream Login via Yahoo.

Well, every step I understood because most of step contains a 302 header redirect, so I got an idea of how the next link would be. But in a step response was 200 success with some content and it redirected to the next link. I am providing a pastebin URL where step one is the request form by the client and step two is the response which contains the 200 success header code with some content and the third step is a request form. This request is done by that second step as it doesn't have a 302 code. It seems like the link formed by the content in the second step. As I am unable to understand from the content how it formed.

PasteBin link: http://pastebin.com/JEUR49C6. The link contains the information of steps.

How should I understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has different ways of logging you in:

1. using a JavaScript client, then getting the cookies in PHP.
2. an [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) connection (really simple). This is the better option if you ask me.

Facebook's Developer Page can tell you how to use OAuth with their site.